# On partial integro-differential equation

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

How to solve the following partial integro-differential equation

\begin{eqnarray}u_t(x,t)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}u(y,t)dy\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})
\end{eqnarray}
Is there any well-posedness theory for such equations? What are the conditions on the initial data $u_0$ for the existence of such a solution.
Please suggest me the references.

It is clear that if $\int u_0=0$ then $u(x,t)=u_0(x)$ is the solution.

Comment: Suggestion: don't use same label for a dummy variable in an integral and also outside it. It leads to unnecessary confusion. As written, for example, this looks like $\partial_x u_t(x,t) = 0$.

Comment: In any case we *do* we $(u_t)_x = 0$ so $u(x,t) = F(t) + G(x)$. The only way we can have a finite integral is if $F(t) = 0$ so you have already found the condition.